# How to remove .pyo anc .pyc from an RPM?

Tags: python, rpm

I have a proxy written in python. I want to create an RPM for this. This rpm will just place the appropriate files at their location. and then some python server will pick them.
Now my question is that whenever I generate the rpm, I am getting .pyo and .pyc files as well for every .py file. I don't need those pyc and pyo files.
Is there any flag or anything that I can do to remove them?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you generate rpms?

Comment: rpmbuild --bb proxy.spec

Comment: Are you sure you don't need those? This page suggests you should, and explains why: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python

Answer (score 6):

I have excluded these .pyc and .pyo files from getting packaged into the RPM by adding lines like this in your RPM specfile:

```
%files
...
...
%exclude /path_to_files/*.pyc
%exclude /path_to_files/*.pyo
```

Answer (score 4):

The *.pyc and *.pyo are being automagically compiled by helper scripts in rpm.

The simplest way to disable is to add "exit 0" at the end of the %install section to disable the running of the helper scripts

Otherwise you will need to change your build configuration and redefine the macros that are being appended to the %install script let when building.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I am getting following error on adding exit 0 at the end of %install script.   error: Could not open %files file /home/pal1/rpmbuild/BUILD/proxy-1.0/debugfiles.list: No such file or directory


RPM build errors:
    Could not open %files file /home/pal1/rpmbuild/BUILD/proxy-1.0/debugfiles.list: No such file or directory

Comment: Try to add `%debug_package %{nil}` in `/etc/rpm/macros`